# Symfony 2 - How can I share data between controllers

Tags: symfony

I need to be able to make some request data from one controller available in another controller.  I can make a service to set the data in one controller, but when the other controller fires and I get the service, a new instance of the service is created.  Is there any way I can make this data static and share it between two controllers?

Comment: How are you calling the second controller? If you are using `{{ render('xxx') }}` in a template then you can call the master request from the `@request_stack` in your second controller.

Comment: The second controller is called from a link on the main page. I can't see how render() will work in my case, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is the controller just a separate page? Could it be passed through a `$_GET` parameter?

Comment: The second controller inserts a new section in the main page using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The same basic things you would do whenever you need information to be available in PHP from a new request:

- Store it in the session. Symfony2 has a great session component for this. Ideal for fleeting data that needs to be saved only while the user is navigating
- Store it in the database. Symfony2 supports Doctrine which makes this very easy. Ideal for permanent storage

Optionally:

- Store it on the filesystem. Not recommended unless it's actually a file, but possible as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. It would seem overkill to store it in the filesystem or the db. I've been avoiding using the session because I was holding out that there might be a way to store it statically in the service. Apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, rather than using the session to store data, I created two separate routes to the same controller action. I added an optional argument in the controller action, with a default value only specified in one of the routes.  I can then test for that argument's value when the controller runs.  In the Twig template that calls this controller action, the path can be generated using either one of these routes, depending on a variable already available.

Bit of a work around, but problem solved!